# How to hide drawer once the applilication starts?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am developing an android application with a navigation drawer. Everything works fine. except that when I start my application the drawer appears automatically. Here what I tried to fix this issue:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            mDrawerLayout);

    // as a solution I added this if-statement
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

But it is not working! . How to hide it once the applilication starts ?

Comment: Drawer normally apears hidden in the activity. Are you sure you are not requesting it to apear somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi u can use following code:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```